# MacBook restarts when idle

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, reboot

MacBook Pro 2019 13" If I don't use the laptop, it goes into sleep mode about 5-10 minutes. When I want to continue working I press any key and I am greeted with a login window, after which I find out that all applications are closed as if a reboot has occurred.

If I work on it and do not allow inactivity for more than 5-10-15 minutes, I do not know the exact duration, everything is OK.

Maybe I incorrectly set some operating system settings or the system restarts one of the applications, But how do I find out?

Comment: Have you [set your Mac to log out when not in use](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-your-mac-to-log-out-when-not-in-use-mchlp2443/mac)?

Comment: looks like a solution! thank you very much, until it repeats!

Answer (score 1):

Answer: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-your-mac-to-log-out-when-not-in-use-mchlp2443/mac

> On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click General.
>
> Click the lock icon  to unlock it, then enter an administrator name and password.
>
> Click Advanced. Select “Log out after... minutes of inactivity.” Set the amount of time before the user is automatically logged out.

@lhf Thanks!